# Count the total number of bullets used in a word document

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a document in which there is text in bullets as well as numbers. I want to find the total number of bullets and numbers the word document has.

### This is a sample text that i tried:

This is a bullet test for the word document

•   Lets work on this to play a game of fame
•   Light the bulb before the candle goes dark
•   Run like there is no tomorrow

I am also putting in numbers because I want to count bullets as well as numbers

1. This is a number
2. This is another number
3. There are so many numbers

---

I have tried the following code:

```
my_file = "Bullet_test.docx"
    from docx import Document
    document = Document(my_file)
    styles = document.styles
```

Reading the bullets

```
from docx.enum.style import WD_STYLE_TYPE
   paragraph_styles = [
        s for s in styles if s.type == WD_STYLE_TYPE.PARAGRAPH
        ]
   paragraph_styles
```

I am getting the following output:

```
[_ParagraphStyle('Normal') id: 106125072,
    _ParagraphStyle('List Paragraph') id: 106126528]
```

I want to find the total number of bullets and numberings which should give me a total of 6 for the sample word document. Could you please let me know what am I doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing wrong is trying to find a bullet by going over `styles`, even though, in your document, you have no `style` called `Bullet` or something like that.

If you want to use `style` to find bullets, you must have them defined as a style (by adding a style called "Bullet").

Here is what I did on my machine:

[image]

After that I ran this:

```
>>> d = Document(my_file)
>>> d.styles
<docx.styles.styles.Styles object at 0x026B4830>
>>> d.styles['Bullet'] # to check that indeed the style 'Bullet' exists
_ParagraphStyle('Bullet') id: 40587152
>>> for p in d.paragraphs:
...     if p.style.name == 'Bullet':
...             print '~'
...
```

and voila, 4 bullets were detected!

```
~
~
~
~
```

---

Adding a style could be done directly using Python, by (taken from [here](http://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/styles-using.html)):

```
>>> from docx.enum.style import WD_STYLE_TYPE
>>> styles = document.styles
>>> style = styles.add_style('Citation', WD_STYLE_TYPE.PARAGRAPH)
>>> style.name
'Citation'
>>> style.type
PARAGRAPH (1)
```

and then applying it by:

```
>>> document = Document()
>>> paragraph = document.add_paragraph()
>>> paragraph.style
<docx.styles.style._ParagraphStyle object at <0x11a7c4c50>
>>> paragraph.style.name
'Normal'
>>> paragraph.style = document.styles['Heading 1']
>>> paragraph.style.name
'Heading 1'
```

Comment: Thanks @CIsForCookies for the answer. For the project I am doing, I would be getting a lot of word documents from various sources and hence adding a style to the document may not be possible. Is there any other way we could find the total number of bullets in a word document? Thanks!

Comment: Not sure... From what I see here `http://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/styles-understanding.html`, `List Bullet` is a default style, so you could use that without any creating & applying styles, but for some reason, on my word it doesn't exist

Comment: I had tried upvoting you but it said it won't show as an upvote but the upvote has been registered.